# UI interface Builder c#

Tags: c#, user-interface, interface-builder

i want the ability to create a UI designer (Winforms/WPF/UI/User interface type agnostic).
The requirment is that it should be  possible to add properties to a device and it should automatically turn up in the UI.The addition of properties would be via a admin screen.

eg. there is a UI object called Order.It should be possible to add a property called ordersoomething to the order object  from the admin screen and it should automatically reflect in the User interface.

i am looking for something that is already available (Open Source/existing stuff etc).

Edit based on a couple if comments.
What i mean by UI agnostic is that i am looking for a architectural pattern. That would fit well.it should not matter if it is Webforms or Silverlight or Winforms.

Regards
David Xavier

Comment: I want the ability to fly, and see through walls.

Comment: What do you mean with "UI agnostic" here? In this scenario the Builder would _be_ the GUI tech.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this C#, make sure you know about [VS LightSwitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch)

Comment: +1 to point out. Sounds exciting...download is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DevExpress Application Frameowrk, something called XAF, see the Developer Express website, it's not for free but not too expensive considering what you are asking, I am not sure if it only targets WindowForms...